# How to get TestComplete results in Visual Studio Online

Tags: visualstudio, testcomplete

I have been trying to get our TC (TestComplete) results in VSO (Visual Studio online) but so far I have not been able to get it to work.

Below is a summary of my findings so far.

The mht file that TC generates is not supported by VSO as far as I can tell.
The xml files that are generated do not work in VSO though xml itself is supported.

It might be possible to get the xml files to work by creating a JUnit template for the xml files but that seems like quite the workaround.

I have also been trying to run MSTest.exe from the commandline and this generates trx files which is supported by VSO but I could not get the tests to work using MSTest and the commandline.

I would like to know how to get our TC test results in VSO and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you read about Integration of TestComplete with Visual Studio, they have a very good documentation here: https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/73372/

Answer (score 1):

If there's an easy way to do this, I don't know it.

That said, it can be done, but depending on exactly what you want it might take some heavy code work: essentially you'd need to run the Test Complete .mht file through an XML transform of some description to reformat it to something VSO recognizes and will display, then attach it to whatever work item in VSO you need it linked to.

If you're wanting full linkup between test cases in VSO and the Test Complete results things get a bit more complicated and would need the TFS API to handle associating various pieces.